# Why does un-named object returned by value get destructed before its conversion operator is called?

Tags: c++, conversion-operator, return-by-value

I have a function which returns an object by value. The recipient variable requires the outward conversion operator on that object to be called.
If I construct the returned object at the return statement (RVO) its destructor gets called before the outward conversion operator.
However, if I name the object, and return that, the outward conversion operator gets called before the object is destructed.
Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>

class Ref {
public:
    Ref(int * ptr) : iptr(ptr) {
        std::cout << "Ref Constructed at: " << long(this) << " Pointing to: " << long(ptr) << '\n';
    }
    Ref(Ref & ref) : iptr(ref) {
        std::cout << "Ref Moved to: " << long(this) << '\n';
        ref.iptr = nullptr;
    }

    operator int () {
        std::cout << "Ref-To int: Temp at: " << long(iptr) << '\n';
        return *iptr;
    }

    operator int* () {
        std::cout << "Ref-To int*: Temp at: " << long(iptr) << '\n';
        return iptr;
    }
    ~Ref() {
        delete iptr;
        std::cout << "Ref at: " << long(this) << " Deleted: " << long(iptr) << '\n';
    }
private:
    int * iptr;
};

Ref foo() {
    int * temp = new int(5);
    Ref retVal(temp); 
    std::cout << "Return named Ref\n";
    return retVal;
}

Ref bar() {
    int * temp = new int(5);
    std::cout << "Return anonymous Ref\n";
    return Ref(temp);
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "*********  Call foo() *************\n";   
    int result = foo();
    std::cout << "\n*********  Call bar() *************\n"; 
    int result2 = bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output from this is:

```
*********  Call foo() *************
Ref Constructed at: 2356880 Pointing to: 5470024
Return named Ref
Ref-To int*: Temp at: 5470024
Ref Moved to: 2356956
Ref at: 2356880 Deleted: 0
Ref-To int: Temp at: 5470024
Ref at: 2356956 Deleted: 5470024

*********  Call bar() *************
Return anonymous Ref
Ref Constructed at: 2356680 Pointing to: 5470024
Ref-To int*: Temp at: 5470024
Ref Constructed at: 2356968 Pointing to: 5470024
Ref at: 2356680 Deleted: 5470024
Ref-To int: Temp at: 5470024
Press any key to continue . . .
```

When bar() is called the reference is deleted before the conversion operator is called, and it crashes.
Also, I don't understand why the Ref to int* conversion is getting called when the return value is being built.

Comment: @Slava The `Ref` copy constructor signature is one of the allowed ones. The lvalue reference parameter does not have to be `const`.

Comment: @juanchopanza you are right, my bad.

Comment: You should paste the two flavors  of test-code, too

Comment: Please give us a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This code is pretty terrible. Sorry. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have replaced the original code with a simplified, complete example. @Jefffrey Why is this code "pretty terrible"? I am experimenting and want to understand why the RVO version behaves differently from the named-return value version. That seems a good enough reason to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is going on

> I don't understand why the Ref to int* conversion is getting called when the return value is being built.

That happens because, apparently, MSVC does not perform RVO in debug mode, so the "copy constructor" (`Ref(Ref&)`) gets called to return from the `foo` function and this gets executed:

```
Ref(Ref & ref) : iptr(ref) {
    // ...
}
```

where `iptr`, of type `int*`, is initialized with the implicit conversion from `ref`.

As [@bogdan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4326278/bogdan) made me notice, this "copy constructor" of yours really has a move constructor semantic, and you should probably write a specific `Ref(Ref&&)` for that instead.

In `bar`, we have that you are building an rvalue `return Ref(temp)` which cannot be bound to a lvalue reference for the `Ref(Ref&)` constructor, and therefore the other constructor is picked and the pointer in copied in (without resetting the temporary one).

When the temporary one gets out of scope, the pointer is `delete`d, and when the constructed object from `bar` also goes out of scope, the same pointer is deleted, causing undefined behaviour (which is the reason of your crash).

#### The C++ way to write that class

Your class has many other issues. For one it can lead to various crashes and it's generally not memory safe. In C++ you would write something like this for that class:

```
class Ref {
public:

    explicit Ref(std::unique_ptr<int> ptr)
        : iptr(std::move(ptr))
        {}
        
    int get() const { return *iptr; }
    int* data() const { return iptr.get(); }

private:

    std::unique_ptr<int> iptr;
    
};
```

or even just `std::unique_ptr`.

The point here is that implicit conversions and manual dynamic memory allocation will often lead to many bugs and "crashes". Avoid them like the plague as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you. That is most helpful. Having fixed the copy constructor and made it &&, both foo and bar behave as I expected them to. I did not use unique_ptr because I wanted to see exactly what was going on.